# Connection between ROS running on PC and mobile robot by TCP

Tags: control, ros, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm new with ROS. I have a robot (Pololu 3pi) with WLAN module. I would like to communicate with that robot wirelessly through TCP or WiFi (to remote control). I was looking some information on this site http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/TCPROS but i couldn't find anything helpful. I would be very grateful for any response.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250286/connection-between-ros-running-on-pc-and-mobile-robot-by-tcp/) by [Cayero](https://answers.ros.org/users/27919/cayero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-12-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2016-12-18**:
Depending on you needs, you may only need to establish the correct RosNetwork settings - specifically, setting ROS_MASTER_URI to be the same on your machine and robot and only launching one roscore. Check out this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines

**Comment by [Cayero](https://answers.ros.org/users/27919/cayero/) on 2016-12-19**:
But how to set ROS_MASTER_URI on my robot (pololu 3pi)?? It has only Atmega328 controller.

**Comment by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) on 2016-12-19**:
applologies to the original post. I didn't look at your specific robot and was thinking you were already runninngvROS on it.

**Comment by [Cayero](https://answers.ros.org/users/27919/cayero/) on 2016-12-19**:
@gvdhoorn using rosserial, should I use arduino platform?
In this way it would look like this:
Arduino connected through wire with PC then Arduino connected with WLAN module through WiFi. Is that possible?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-20**:
I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly. `rosserial` is typically used to bridge an Arduino into a ROS node graph. The connection can be serial, serial over usb or a (wireless) network. I'm not sure why you'd want both a wired and a wireless connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could probably make use of `rosserial`. You don't want / need to run a full-blown ROS on such restricted hardware.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0